# Core java regarding generic and collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, hashmap

```
class ByValue<String, Integer extends Comparable<Integer>> implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    }
```

This is the code to sort map by value, This code is working fine but i have some doubts here regarding basic java techniques and syntax used here,

First thing is, i am not able to understand `class ByValue<String, Integer extends Comparable<Integer>>`. Are we making the class generic while declaring it,because i used this generic thing in methods only, or what we are doing basically here?

Second thing is I can either use `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` or `Entry<String, Integer>` what is the difference between these two statements here? Both are working fine for me in the code.

Comment: I doubt your code is doing what you think it's doing. Look into _type shadowing_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are we making the class generic while declaring it,because i used this generic thing in methods only, or what we are doing basically here?

Yes, the class defined like this is generic and its type-parameters are called `Integer` and `String`. These, however, are **not** the types `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.String` - the parameters, defined like that are *shadowing* the actual types `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.String`, so I advice you to follow the well-known approach of naming type parameters with a single upper-case letter:

```
class ByValue<T, U extends Comparable<Integer>> implements Comparator<Map.Entry<T, U>> {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<T, U> o1, Map.Entry<T, U> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
}
```

This way, you can note, that your (generic) class, doesn't implement `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`. If you really need that, there's actually no need the class to be generic, but just to implement the `Comparator` interface, parameterized with *specific* types:

```
class ByValue implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
}
```

---

> Second thing is I can either use Map.Entry or Entry what is the difference between these two statements here?

There's no actual difference. If you have an `import` statement like this one:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

then you could just use `Entry`, without pointing out the class where it's defined (`Map`, in this case).

Comment: what does it mean "shadowing the actual types" ?  @dsh

Comment: It means that if you define a variable `Integer x = null` it will not be of type `java.lang.Integer`, but will be of type the class-scoped type-parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
class ByValue<String, Integer extends Comparable<Integer>> 
    implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
```

> Are we making the class generic while declaring it,because i used this generic thing in methods only, or what we are doing basically here?

What you're doing here is actually messing everything up incorrectly.  Right now you're making new type variables named `String` and `Integer`, that have no actual relationship to the real `String` and `Integer` types.  This is essentially the same thing as `class ByValue<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparable<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, except the type variables are named `String` and `Integer`, which is terribly confusing.

Instead, it should just be

```
class ByValue implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
```

> Second thing is I can either use Map.Entry or Entry what is the difference between these two statements here? Both are working fine for me in the code.

There is no difference.  It's just two ways of referring to the same type.

Answer (score 1):

> Second thing is I can either use Map.Entry or Entry what is the difference between these two statements here? Both are working fine for me in the code.

Within the declaration of the interface `java.util.Map` is declared an interface `Entry`.  You can have either of the following:

```
import java.util.Map;

Map.Entry<String, Integer>
```

or you can have

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;

Entry<String, Integer>
```

Both are the same.

Comment: Entry is the static inner class in Map thatsy we can either use any of the statement ? this u mean to say ? @dsh

Comment: Yes.  Map defines a static inner interface Entry.  The difference is in the import statement.  (I prefer Map.Entry just so it is obvious when reading the code what sort of "Entry" it is)

Comment: Thankyou  for your reply @dsh